# Не получается задать значение через конструктор

Tags: javascript

Есть простые классы, у каждого есть метод `toHTML()` и конструктор.

Пример класса:

```js
export class Toolbar {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  toHTML() {
    return `toolbar, id ${this.id}`
  }
}
```

В классе Excel есть метод getRoot() в котором есть forEach

```js
export class Excel {
  constructor(selector, options) {
    this.$el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.components = options.components || [];
  }
  getRoot() {
    const $root = document.createElement('div');
    $root.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello world!</h1>`;
    console.log(this.components);
    let num = 0;
    this.components.forEach(Component => {
      var component = new Component(num);
      console.log(component.toHTML());
      num++;
    });
    return $root;
  }
  render() {

    console.log(this.$el);
    this.$el.append(this.getRoot());
    // this.$el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<h1>Hello world!</h1>`);
  }
}
```

В index.js стартует этот код:

```js
const excel = new Excel("#app", {
  components: [Header, Toolbar, Formula, Table]
});

excel.render();
```

В классе `Excel` в `forEach` в конструктор класса передаётся `let num`. Всё работает. Значение через конструктор задаётся. Но если вот эти классы унаследованы от другого, как то так:

```js
export class Toolbar extends ExcelComponent {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  toHTML() {
    return `toolbar, id ${this.id}`
  }
}

export class ExcelComponent extends DOMListener {

}

export class DOMListener {

}
```

ТО возникает следующая ошибка (если значение id передаём в конструктор класса который унаследован от другого)

> Toolbar.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')

Так как будто свойства id нигде нет. Вопрос почему так происходит?

Comment: И хочу дополнить. Если в этом классе убрать конструктор
class Toolbar extends ExcelComponent{
    
    toHTML() {
        return `toolbar, id ${this.id}`
    }
}
и свойство id добавлять так:
this.components.forEach(Component => {
            var component = new Component;
            component.id = num;
            console.log(component.toHTML());
            num++;
        });
то всё работает. id видно

Comment: при наследовании должна была быть другая ошибка: об обращении к this в конструкторе до вызова `super`

Answer (score 0):

сорян вопрос решён. надо делать конструктор в главном классе от которого все наследуется и всё заработает

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).